# jQuery event not working as it should

Tags: jquery, html

As I try and say before all of my questions - I'm new to this whole thing.  With that being said.  I'm working on some client side validation of passwords.  I'm trying to make a script that will fill a span with an image if the passwords either don't match, or if either field is blank on blur.  I have been unable to get it to show that passwords match, even when I know they do.  Here is the relevant code:

html:

```
    <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for="r_password">Password:</label></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="password" name="r_password" id="r_password"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><span id="r_passwordFeedback"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for"r_vpassword">Verify Password</label></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="password" name="r_vpassword" id="r_vpassword"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><span id="r_vpasswordFeedback"></span></div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $("#r_password").blur(function() {
    if ($("#r_password").val() != $("#r_vpassword").val()) { $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(deleteImg + "Passwords do not match"); }
    else if ($("#r_password").val() || $("#r_vpassword").val() === "") { $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(deleteImg + " Required"); } 
    else { $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(acceptImg); }
});
$("#r_vpassword").blur(function() {
    if($("#r_password").val() != ("#r_vpassword").val()) { $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(deleteImg); }
    else if($("#r_password").val() || $("#r_vpassword").val() === "") { $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(deleteImg); }
    else { $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(acceptImg); }
});
```

Any help you might be able to shine on my little issue would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typho here `if($("#r_password").val() != ("#r_vpassword").val())`.

The `$` is missing.

I think its, `if($("#r_password").val() != $("#r_vpassword").val())`

Comment: Is "typho" a tyop or a clever joke?

Comment: Nice catch.  Silly little typos seem to get me all the time.  Thank you :)

Comment: @ mu is too short Its another `tyop` :)

Answer (score 2):

HIya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/dTEVF/8/ **another** different version - you can type and match http://jsfiddle.net/Bjc8t/ (Just thought of sharing)

If I may recommend try using validation framework if you have bigger application on the roll! Bit extra what you asked but here you go try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/W5RaU/ :)

**jquery code**

```
$("#r_password").blur(function() {
    if ($("#r_password").val() != $("#r_vpassword").val()) {
        $("#r_passwordFeedback").html("Passwords do not match");
    }
    else if ($("#r_password").val() === "" || $("#r_vpassword").val() === "") {
        $("#r_passwordFeedback").html(" Required");
    }
    else {
        $("#r_passwordFeedback").html("matches");
    }

});

$("#r_vpassword").blur(function() {
    if ($("#r_password").val() != $("#r_vpassword").val()) {
        $("#r_passwordFeedback").html("not matching image");
    }
    else if ($("#r_password").val() === "" || $("#r_vpassword").val() === "") {
        $("#r_passwordFeedback").html("empty");
    }
    else {
        $("#r_passwordFeedback").html("password match");
    }
});​
```